# Hibernate returns null for an integer after getting the data from db in Java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
Class
{
    private int objectId;
}
<result property="objectId" column="id" />
```

SQL MAP

Query returns null and the int field is set to null.
so this line of code

```
object.getObjectId();
```

throws a null pointer exception.

How do i check if objectId is null or not? I see people using ResultSet in java, but i cannot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type from `int` to `Integer`. Then it'll be able to be `null`, and you'll be able to check this at runtime.